# Excel - Advanced filter with wildcards

Tags: excel, filter, wildcard, advanced-filter

I am trying to filter (DATA > Advanced under "Sort & Filter) a range of fields based on a wildcard + text based on the info I'm finding here: https://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html

But when I use the * wildcard, it is returning filtered results such as *string*, instead of *string. For instance, I am using *-1 to try and get any field in this column ending in "-1", but I am receiving results such as 15-110 (with -1 in the middle).

Sample:
[image: Filtered output highlighted in red is unwanted]

I don't want the output highlighted in red to be included in the filtered results. Just the remaining 3 items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following as your criteria:

```
="=*-1"
```

This would work because we can mix up a wildcard with these logical operators as described as below to check for an exact match:

[image]